# Javascript Sieve of Eratosthenes with input text field

Tags: javascript, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I am having some issues implementing the Sieve of Eratosthenes javascript found [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#JavaScript). I know some questions have been asked about this in the past, but it'
s a bit over my head.  I copied the script from the web page and only added the text field input at the top.  I am trying to get an input from a text box, then the code will output the prime numbers up to that number. When I call the function with a button, nothing happens.  Thanks in advance for any help you can give me.

```
function displayNextPrime(limit) {
    // Sieve of Eratosthenes to determine the string of prime numbers?  Then desiplay the next one?
    var limit = document.getElementById("number").value;
    var primes = [];
    if (limit >= 2) {
        var nums = new Array(limit - 1);
        for (var i = 2; i <= limit; i++)
            nums[i - 2] = i;
        var last_prime;
        var idx = 0;
        while ((last_prime = nums[idx]) <= Math.sqrt(limit)) {
            if (last_prime != null)
                for (var i = idx + last_prime; i < limit - 1; i += last_prime)
                    nums[i] = null;
            idx++;
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++)
            if (nums[i] != null)
                primes.push(nums[i]);
    }
    return primes;
    var primes = erasthenes(100);
    if (typeof print == "undefined") {
        print = (typeof WScript != "undefined") ? WScript.Echo : alert;
    }
    //primes.toString();
    //document.getElementById("erasthenes").innerHTML = primes;
    print(primes);
}
```

Comment: Look at your browser dev console, this line is probably throwing an error: `var primes = erasthenes(100);`.

Comment: I stepped through the code with the dev console, and that code with everything underneath it wasn't touched.  I added a innerHTML to return primes, and everything seems to be working now.  Thank you for the help.

Comment: You're welcome. I believe it was throwing an error because you renamed the function to `displayNextPrime`